# What does it mean when Hobbes says “round quadrangle” signifies nothing?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-language, hobbes

When Hobbes claims that “round quadrangle” (*Leviathan*, ch.IV) signifies nothing, what does that mean and why does it signify nothing?

Comment: It is a "description" that is contradictory, because a quadrangle cannot be round. Thus, it is a "void" name that does not refer to something. See [Hobbes: Language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hobbes/#2.2).

Comment: The unit circle in the taxicab metric is a square. Philosophers should stop claiming there are no square circles, since there are. Wikipedia has a picture of a square circle here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Answer (score 1):

See the full paragraph of [*Leviathan*, Ch.IV On speech](https://web.archive.org/web/20030308064707/http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/phl302/texts/hobbes/leviathan-a.html#CHAPTER%20IV):

> "when men make a name of two names, whose significations are contradictory and inconsistent; as this name, an incorporeal body [...]. For whensoever any affirmation is false, the two names of which it is composed, put together and made one, signify nothing at all. For example, if it be a false affirmation to say a quadrangle is round, the word round quadrangle signifies nothing, but is a mere sound."

Thus, a combination of names that is contradictory fails to *signify* because it is a "void" expression that does not refer to an existing object.

Comment: I'd say it's worse than not referring to an existing object - I don't think Hobbes would put this in the same category as "the duck on my head." "Round quadrangle" is not only non-referring, it's not *coherent.*

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Sorell points out, 'There is no evidence that [Hobbes] was concerned to elaborate a free-standing theory of reference, let alone a full-blown philosophy of language' (T. Sorell, Hobbes, London: RKP, 1986: 38. So there may be no precise answer to your question but something more can definitely be said.

Hobbes has the idea of 'Absurdity', equally referred to as 'Insignificant' [speech] and 'Non-sense': Leviathan, ch. V. The mark of absurdity, hence of insignificant speech or speech which 'signifies nothing', is that it does not express a coherent conception.

How so? The conception of a round quadrilateral is incoherent because it involves a contradiction: 'round' implies 'not quadrilateral' and 'quadrilateral' implies 'not round' (at the same time in the same respects).

That is how Hobbes would probably have explained his position. He certainly uses the term 'contradiction' when he talks of a round quadrilateral. Perhaps we can state his position in modern terms by saying that for Hobbes 'round quadrilateral' signifies nothing in the sense that it is *logically impossible* for anything to be at the same time and in the same respects both round and quadrilateral.

I might add that, having created a logical space for speech which 'signifies nothing', Hobbes has more controversial occupants for it than the round quadrilateral. Ghosts join the gods and demons of the Ancient Greeks along with such 'absurdities' of Catholic doctrine as 'incorporeal substances', transubstantiation and free will. (Leviathan, ch. 34, 45 & 46.) I make no comment on these examples - I merely let Hobbes speak.